# Adding <path> tag to pom.xml file

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, pom.xml, android-pay

It is my first time working with Google's App Engine project and with Maven.

I'm working on the [Save to Android Pay Quick Start for Java](https://github.com/android-pay/s2ap-quickstart-java) and When I run `mvn appengine:devserver` (according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/samples/quickstart-java#step_3_configure_and_build_the_project)) the server is launched and start listening on my localhost and a port I specified in the `pom.xml` file like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.9</version>
    <configuration>
    <port>1234</port>
    <address>0.0.0.0</address>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So in this case, when I'll open my browser and go to `http://localhost:1234` I will send a request to the server.

**My goal** is to add a path to that address so instead of opening `localhost:1234` I'll be able to open `localhost:1234/somePath`. I know I can't just add `<path>` tag to the `pom.xml` file, and I couldn't find any other way to do it.

Is there a way to add a path to that address?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way... And [looking at the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/devappserver/AbstractDevAppServerMojo.java#L214), it strongly suggests that it isn't possible.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for the link.